# Short form of lambda doesn't work in inner function

Tags: scala

Reading `Advanced Scala With Cats` I can see this line on page 60:

```
fa.map(g(f(_))) == fa.map(f).map(g)
```

I'm trying to do something like:

```
  val l = List(1, 2, 3)
  def g(v: Int) = v + 1 
  def f(v: Int) = v * 2

  l.map(g(f(_)))
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(25, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: Int
  l.map(g(f(_)))
```

This is okay:

```
  l.map(x => g(f(x)))
  l.map(g(_))
```

Can't understand why my example doesn't work, but in the book it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)
  def g(v: Int) = v + 1 
  def f(v: Int) = v * 2

  l.map(g(f(_)))
```

I will try to split your  `l.map(g(f(_)))` into equivalent steps

```
val  fun1 =  f(_) // this returns a partially applied function Int => Int.
```

then

```
g(fun1)  // will give you error because function g requires int as an argument whereas we are passing func1: Int => Int as input. This is the exact issue comes when you do g(f(_)).
```

The alternatives that you have mentioned is correct. My idea here is to demonstrate the ability of Scala’s function composition. I would like to do the same thing other available approaches.

```
 val fun = f _ andThen g _
 l.map(fun)
```

Same can be done with `compose`  as well.

```
val fun1 =  g _ compose f _
l.map(fun1)
```

Remember that composition is available only on Unary functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in following way:

```
scala> val g:Int => Int = _ + 1
g: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val f:Int => Int = _ * 2
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l map (g compose f)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 5, 7)
```

When declaring a `def` you get a method which expects an argument provided when using its name in the code.
When declaring a function as a `val` you get a pure `Function1` instance and you can operate on them with functional combinators normally.

Comment: Have no idea how it could even work. Probably if that book is old enough try to compile with some older Scala version. Underscore version definitely will not work in this variant in 2.12.6, for example this will work: `l.map(x => g(f(x)))`
Also some books have related GitHub repo with the code of all examples/exercises. If there is no such repo then a piece of the code in the book itself is not guaranteed to be 100% correct.